# Replace a string depending on what the current value is with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL that is www.site.com, I wish to replace the www with UK, but I also need to replace the UK to either CA or HK, depending on what region the USER is in.

I currently have this code

```
    oQuery('a.product-list-item').each(function(){
  var href = oQuery(this).attr('href');
  // change the href to something else
  var newhref = href.replace(/www/, 'uk');
  // update href
  oQuery(this).attr('href', newhref);
});
```

But this doesn't account for if they are changing from the www to CA, or UK, or if they are changing from the UK to HK or CA to HK, I assume that a regex could be used in the replace function, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the question? How to detect the region?

Comment: unclear, [ask] [mcve]

Comment: What is the complete `href` value, and which part of it depends on the region?

Comment: Yes and no, the url in the address bar changes, but the links to other products keep the www in the href, so when you click on a product, it redirects you to the homepage for the www site instead of going to the product on whatever region your on. For example, if I'm on productA and on uk.site.com, the product url is still www.site.com/productA instead of uk.site.com/productA, I need the URLs to change to reflect the specific region

Comment: the complete href is http%3A%2F%2Fwww.katesomerville.com%2Fnourish-hydrating-firming-mist  I wish to change the www, to UK, CA, or HK, depending on what the current region is set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this replace variant:

```
var regions = ['uk', 'ca', 'be', 'cz', 'hu', 'ma'];
oQuery('a.product-list-item').each(function(index){
    var href = oQuery(this).attr('href');
    // change the href to something else
    var newhref = href.replace(/\w+(\.site\.com)/, regions[index] + '$1');
    // update href
    oQuery(this).attr('href', newhref);
});
```

Just put the correct sitename where I have put "site.com", making sure you escape a dot with a backslash.

Comment: So could my region variable be an array?

Comment: So the regex works, but I can't use an array for the region variable.

Comment: Sure you can, it just depends on which element of your array you want to pick. See my updated answer which defines an array, and then picks an entry from it in the `replace`. I don't know on which basis you want to select the region, so your code will look different. Maybe you want the same region to be applied for every iteration. Then just first define the index before you start looping.

Comment: Did it work out for you with arrays? Could you let me know?

Comment: ended up using the following  

var subdomain=window.location.href.split("/")[2].split(".")[0];
oQuery('a.product-list-item').each(function(){
  // grab the href
  var href = decodeURIComponent(oQuery(this).attr('href'));
  var newhref = href.replace(/\w+(\.katesomerville\.com)/, subdomain + '$1');
  
  // update href
  oQuery(this).attr('href', newhref);
});

Answer (score 0):

You can build alternation regexp on the fly.

```
var regionList = ['www', 'uk', 'ca', 'hk'];
var regionRegex = new RegExp('\b(?:'+regionList.join('|')+')\b');
!function($){
  function regionateLinks(region) {
    $('a').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(regionRegex, region));
    });
  }
}(oQuery);

regionateLinks('uk');
```

It works like:

```
'http://www.example.com'.replace(/\b(?:www|uk|ca|hk)\b/, 'uk')
```